# A tough table transforming into XML

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, .net-2.0

I have a DataTable which I select from database (Well, these data cross several tables, after the query and putting into a DataTable, it shows at below)

ColumnA    ColumnB 
a                     11
b                     33
b                     44
a                     22
b                     55

but I want to transform it into an XML like this

```
<root>
   <header name ='a'>
       <item name='11' />
       <item name='22' />
   </header>
   <header name ='b'>
       <item name='33' />
       <item name='44' />
       <item name='55' />
   </header>

</root>
```

Is there an easy way to implement it by C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, second approach after learning that the data is available in a `DataTable` to begin with.

The code is a bit more involved, since based on a DataTable, you can't really do much in terms of grouping etc. I am building up the `XmlDocument` (since you're on .NET 2.0) while scanning through the rows of data. I need to keep track of the `<header>` elements in a dictionary, in order to add a second, third entry with the same "ColumnA" value to that already existing `XmlElement` in the document - it's a bit involved, but if you study it carefully, I hope you see it's really no trickery or anything - just a bit of bookkeeping along the way of building the `XmlDocument`:

```
// create the XmlDocument and add <root> node
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));

// dictionary to keep track of <header> nodes
Dictionary<string, XmlNode> nodesPerColumnA = new Dictionary<string, XmlNode>();

// Loop through data rows
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
   // extract values for ColumnA and ColumnB as strings
   string columnAValue = row["ColumnA"].ToString();
   string columnBValue = row["ColumnB"].ToString();

   // create a new <item> XmlNode and fill its attribute @Name 
   XmlElement newNode = doc.CreateElement("item");

   XmlAttribute newNodeAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
   newNodeAttribute.InnerText = columnBValue;

   newNode.Attributes.Append(newNodeAttribute);

   // check if we already have a <header> node for that "ColumnA" value
   if(nodesPerColumnA.ContainsKey(columnAValue))
   {
       // if so - just add <item> below that <header>
       XmlNode parent = nodesPerColumnA[columnAValue];

       parent.AppendChild(newNode);
   }
   else
   {
       // if not - create appropriate <header> node and its @name attribute
       XmlElement header = doc.CreateElement("header");

       XmlAttribute headerAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
       headerAttr.InnerText = columnAValue;

       header.Attributes.Append(headerAttr);

       header.AppendChild(newNode);

       doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(header);

       // store that <header> xmlnode into the dictionary for future use
       nodesPerColumnA.Add(columnAValue, header);
    }
 }

 // check the contents of the XmlDocument at the end
 string xmlContents = doc.InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 5):

Why bother with C# ?? You can do it in T-SQL directly (SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA AS '@name',
    (SELECT ColumnB AS '@name' 
     FROM YourTable t 
     WHERE t.ColumnA = YourTable.ColumnA 
     FOR XML PATH('item'), TYPE)
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    ColumnA
FOR XML PATH('header'), ROOT('root')
```

Gives you:

```
<root>
  <header name="a">
    <item name="11" />
    <item name="22" />
  </header>
  <header name="b">
    <item name="33" />
    <item name="44" />
    <item name="55" />
  </header>
</root>
```

You can execute this SQL query using standard ADO.NET `SqlCommand` and get back the XML nicely formatted already.

Marc

Comment: Hey Marc,thanks for your response.It's a great work if the data is IN a database table.I'm sorry that I didn't propose my question correctly,I have revised it.How to transfrom a DataTable into an XML above?Thanks in advance=)

Comment: Hmm.... that's not going to be all that easy. I see two ways: 1) manually iterate through the DataTable and build up your XmlDocument as you go, or 2) save the DataTable to XML (DataTable.WriteXml()) and then do a XSLT transform on that

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ:-

```
var qry = from row in Table
          group row by row.ColumnA into header
          select header;

var elem = new XElement("root");

foreach (var header in qry)
{
  var elemHead = new XElement("header", new XAttribute("name", header.Key));
  elem.Add(elemHead);
  foreach (var item in header)
    elemHead.Add(new XElement("item", new XAttribute("name", item.ColumnB)));
}
// the variable elem contains the result.
```

Comment: Hey buddy,I think your solution might work well under .Net 3.5,but I'm using 2.0 and only a newbie to LINQ.Could you help me out with other solution?Thanks in advance=)

Answer (score -1):

This will do it using .NET 3.5 and the XDocument

```
XDocument yourDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("root",
    new XElement("header",
        new XAttribute("name", "a"),
        new XElement("item",
            new XAttribute("name", "11")),
        new XElement("item",
            new XAttribute("name", "22"))),
    new XElement("header",
        new XAttribute("name", "b"),
        new XElement("item",
            new XAttribute("name", "33")),
        new XElement("item",
            new XAttribute("name", "44")),
        new XElement("item",
            new XAttribute("name", "55")))));
```

Comment: @marc_s: Shuo didn't specify the origin of the table data.  Could be in objects already.

Comment: well, when I read "*I want to transform a Table like this*" I would assume he means he has a database table, no?

Comment: Hey David,I'm using .Net 2.0 and the data is not hard coded,it's selecting  from database dynamicly.